# What is the event called when a text inside textbox changes?

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).delegate("input#search-champions", "change", function(e)
```

Whenever I change the value inside `search-champions`, it I have to click outside of the textbox to make it work. I want function to run whenever the value inside textbox changes.

I forgot what it is called, but it's the same system Google uses for it's searches. You write A, and it'll show you results with A.

Comment: `keyup` || `keypress`.

Comment: Is `$("#search-champions").change(function() { ... });` not working?

Comment: `change` is only trigged when the field loses focus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try binding to the `keyup` event instead:

```
$(document).delegate("#search-champions", 'keyup', function(e)
```

By the way, there should be no need to prepend your selector with `input` - IDs should be unique anyway!

Answer (score 1):

change event does not work for textbox. instead change you can use key up or key press event.
What you want we call it as auto complete.
so best way to do that is on keyup event

```
$(document).delegate("input#search-champions", "keyup", function(e){
var elm=$(this);
var str=elm.val();
//now you can get word starting from a either from some array or server call or ajax.

});
```

If you are using jquery ui. It has autocomplete feature.

http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

$(document).delegate("input#search-champions", "change", function(e)

Comment: `change` does work for `input` elements, but only when they are blurred.